# How do I make an horizontal list-horizontal view-problem

Tags: html, css, list

I do have a problem in showing my list horizontally.

[image]

Now this is my code:

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}

.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 40%;
  top: 60%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 999;
}

.navigation li {
display:inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.navigation li:hover, .navigation li.selected {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  transform: scale(1.7);
 
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li class="selected"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

The problem happens when I make the list horizontal display:inline-block; but I also noticed that changing the margin to 0px will not happen anymore, even if that is not the style I´m looking for. 
Some tips? I really need help
I really n

Comment: Your snippet seems to work fine.

Comment: Running the code snippet shows the correct and desired design. What is your problem?

Comment: You need to provide us with a _proper_ [mre] that illustrates your issue first of all. Secondly, what are you talking about regarding the margin?

Comment: I know it should be fine, but then the last link appears off, see the picture I´ve attached...something must be wrong... I don´t understand

Comment: I´m not sure... but if I set  so the margin is 0px

.navigation li {
display:inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;

}

The dots are align.. no off position

Comment: Which  device width/height you have this  issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to solve the problem:
I changed the margin values to the displayed one.
Now my bullet points are aligned !
Thank you all for the help!

```css
.navigation li {
display:inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0 30px 0; 
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
```